# search duplicate element array

Tags: arrays, bash, duplicates

This one work:

```
arr[0]="XX1 1"
arr[1]="XX2 2" 
arr[2]="XX3 3"
arr[3]="XX4 4"
arr[4]="XX5 5"
arr[5]="XX1 1"
arr[6]="XX7 7"
arr[7]="XX8 8"

duplicate() { printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | sort -cu |& awk -F: '{ print $5 }'; }

duplicate_match=$(duplicate)

echo "array: ${arr[@]}"

# echo "duplicate: $duplicate_match"

[[ ! $duplicate_match ]] || { echo "Found duplicate:$duplicate_match"; exit 0; }

echo "no duplicate"
```

with same code, this one doesn't work, why ?

```
arr[0]="XX"
arr[1]="wXyz" 
arr[2]="ABC"
arr[3]="XX"
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually work, because `sort -cu` fails when the input is not already sorted; the duplicate it finds in the first data set just happens to be the first item that occurs out of sorted order.

Comment: the pipe-ampersand combination is only valid in c-shell, not in bash

Comment: @chepner Thanks, i will search for how to sort my array in the right place.

Comment: @thom `|&` was added to `bash` as well in version 4.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I stand corrected. pipe-ampersand is indeed valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check duplicates this code is much simpler and works in both cases:

```
uniqueNum=$(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"|awk '!($0 in seen){seen[$0];c++} END {print c}')

(( uniqueNum != ${#arr[@]} )) && echo "Found duplicates"
```

**EDIT:** To print duplicates use this awk:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"|awk '!($0 in seen){seen[$0];next} 1'
```

Awk command stores in an array `seen` if a line isn't already part of `seen` array and next move to the next line. `1` in the end prints only those lines that are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, i need to study your code to fully understand it, how can i return the duplicate element in echo with it please? Also anyone can correct my code please? i'm on this since two hour and finishing using another code without understanding mine is frustrating :(

Comment: See chepner's answer below why your code failed if you want to understand it.

Comment: I have also added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @Neeraj: Try this: `printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | awk '!seen[$0]++ {} END {print length(seen)}'`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly silly solution here. I just wanted to see if I could do this in a single command without explicit pipes. (I think for very large arrays/array elements, [explicit pipes might actually be more efficient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219806/356395).)

Note that this is a test for the presence of duplicate array elements, and doesn't output the duplicates themselves, although the `awk` command on its own will do that. Also note that if you're unlucky enough to have array elements that contain spaces, the below won't evaluate as described.

```
[[ $( awk -v RS=" " ' a[$0]++ ' <<< "${arr[@]} " ) ]] && echo "dups found"
```

---

Explanation:

`awk -v RS=" "`

- do the subsequent `awk` command on each input record with space as the record separator. Basically, this will make `awk` treat each array element as a separate "line".

`' a[$0]++ '`

- `awk` command that does two things:

  - return at the value at key `$0` in array `a`. If this is greater than 0, print the line. Compare to `awk ' { $1=$2 } 1 '`
  - Add 1 to the value at key `$0` in array `a`.

`<<< "${arr[@]} "`

- as the input of the `awk` command, use the string created when you print each element in `arr` as a separate word, i.e. separated by space **PLUS AN ADDITIONAL SPACE AT THE END**.
- The **space between `}` and `"` is actually really important**, because without it the final array element will *not* have a space after it and therefore will *not* be counted as a distinct "record" by `awk`.

`[[ $( ... )  ]]`

- If the containing `awk` command gives any output at all, the test evaluates to `0`, i.e. TRUE.