# Find multiple duplicates and their indices in array using Bash?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have an array with the following values:

```
list=("abc" "abcd" "abc" "abcde" "abcde" "abcdf" "abc")
```

Is there a way to get the indices of the duplicates into another array, like:

```
abc_position_list=(0, 2, 6)
abcde_position_list=(3, 4)
```

I managed to get all indices into a single array, but this way, you wouldn't know what which indices have the same value.

Is this even possible to do with bash, or would maybe python be more suitable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [search duplicate element array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055238/search-duplicate-element-array)

Comment: `0, 2, 6` - do you want the elements in array with commas?

Comment: @KamilCuk no, sorry, without commas.

Comment: Use a different language if you need to do this much work on a data structure. A `bash` array is suitable for little more than storing a sequence of items for use as arguments to another command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `printf "%s\n" ${list[@]}` - Print the array as newline separated elements.
2. `nl -w1` - Add another column - number to each element.
3. `sort -k2` Sort the list on the values
4. `uniq -f1 -D` - Print duplicated elements ignoring the first column.

With:

```
printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | nl -w1 | sort -k2 | uniq -f1 -D
```

You'll get;

```
1   abc
3   abc
7   abc
4   abcde
5   abcde
```

So now it's time to create arrays. Because you want to have array names extracted from the list, I guess we have to use `eval`, [which is very unsafe](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

1. Normally read the resulting list using `while read`.
2. Use eval to add new elements to the arrays.

So the following code:

```
printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | nl -w1 | sort -k2 | uniq -f1 -D | 
{
   while read -r n v; do 
      eval "${v}_position_list+=(\"\$n\")"; 
   done;
   declare -p abc_position_list abcde_position_list; 
}
```

will make the `declare -p` output two array declarations:

```
declare -a abc_position_list=([0]="1" [1]="3" [2]="7")
declare -a abcde_position_list=([0]="4" [1]="5")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
list_items = ["abc", "abcd", "abc", "abcde", "abcde", "abcdf", "abc"]
counters = {}

for item in list_items:
    if item not in counters:
        counters[item] = [i for i, x in enumerate(list_items) if x == item ]
print counters
```